# what is the max size of video by using google photoslibrary API?

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I try to upload a video (mp4) which is 3.9GB by using the google photoslibrary api.
But it return 400 error.
Is there any file size limit for video?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Google Developer Documentation

> All media items uploaded to Google Photos using the API are stored in
>   full resolution at original quality. They count toward the user’s
>   storage.
>
> Note: If your uploads exceed 25MB per user, your application should
>   remind the user that these uploads will count towards storage in their
>   Google Account.

So After 25 MB it will be stored in their Google Account.IF they have that much amount of free space than yes , they can upload . If they don't have that much space available then they have to update their storage plan.

And About Your Error Code.

**Exceeding quota limits**

> If the quota of requests to the Library API is exceeded, the API
>   returns an error code 429 and a message that the project has exceeded
>   the quota

So it will be Error Code 429 not 400 (in your case).
For detail Information you can find it [here](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/api-limits-quotas)

Comment: For the storage quota, I am using a google education suite account which is unlimited storage. I can upload the 4GB file to google photo by the web interface, but I cannot upload by using the API.